# Проблема с воспроизведением звука в голосовом канале

Tags: discord.py, discord, pycord, yt-dlp

У меня есть код, который может работать без ошибок и бот может подключиться к голосовому каналу, но при присоединении он ничего не делает. И он тоже ничего не отправляет. Мой файл ffmpeg.exe находится в том же каталоге, что и main.py. Я пытался сделать это другими способами, но столкнулся с той же проблемой.

main.py:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
import yt_dlp

bot = discord.Bot()

@bot.slash_command(name="play", help="Play music")
async def play(ctx, url):
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
        if ctx.author.voice:
            channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
            vc = await channel.connect()

            await play_music(vc, url)
        else:
            await ctx.respond("You are not connected to a voice channel.")
    else:
        await ctx.respond("I'm already connected to a voice channel.")

async def play_music(voice_client, url):
    ffmpeg_path = "ffmpeg.exe"
    voice_client.volume = 0.5
    voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url, executable=ffmpeg_path), after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```